# Searching multiple patterns (words) with ack?

Tags: linux, grep, ack, ag

I want to search multiple `patterns` in a `directory` containing `recursive directories` and `files`.

I know command for `grep` which is as follows

```
grep -e '(pattern1)|(pattern2)'
```

or

```
grep -r -E  'string1|string2|string3' /var/www/http
```

What is the command for that using `ack` or `ag`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
ack -R 'string1|string2'
```

As `-R` is the default, you can omit it:

```
ack 'string1|string2'
```

---

From `man ack`:

> **-r**, **-R**, --recurse
>
> Recurse into sub-directories. This is the default and just here for
>   compatibility with grep. You can also use it for turning --no-recurse
>   off.

---

If you want to get the pattern from a file, say /path/to/patterns.file, you can use:

```
ack "$(cat /path/to/patterns.file)"
```

or equivallently:

```
ack "$(< /path/to/patterns.file)"
```

I cannot find an exact equivalent to `grep -f`.

Comment: What do you mean? To store the output in a file or to read the patterns from a file? Please provide the equivalent in `grep` to know exactly to what functionality you are referring to.

Comment: read the patterns from a file something like `grep -f pattern.txt` also if I keeping them in a file is it necessary to start pattern with some special character like `^`

Comment: @SandipPingle uhms, I cannot find an equivalent, so I suggest getting it with `ack "$(< /path/to/patterns.file)" *`. See update.

Comment: `ack "$(cat /path/to/patterns.file)" *` is working fine, with by keeping patterns in file `|` separated like `pat1|pat2`

Comment: do you know any efficient way to keep `output` also in a file currently I am using `ack "$(< /path/to/patterns.file)" * > output.txt` but problem is reading/editing `output` file is difficult.

Comment: @SandipPingle you can maybe use `-l`, `--sort-files`, etc. It really depends on how you want the output. Take a good look at `man ack`.

Comment: is the `*` really needed to search in the current folder and all its subfolders ? works here without (might have been different when the question was asked, though...)

Comment: @ssc you are right, it is not necessary, like when you do `grep -R ...`. Using it does not harm because it expands to all the elements in the current dir, but at the end this is something that `-R` already does. Updated.

Answer (score 7):

The ack command can also string along with pipes.
For example the first ack finds files containing **pattern1** then pipe that to another ack to search just those files for **pattern2**

```
ack -l 'pattern1' | ack -x 'pattern2'
```

The **-l** parameter means to just list the matching files (instead of the matching text). The **-x** parameter means to search just the files piped to it. This is similar to narrowing down the files for the next ack search.

```
ack -l 'pattern1' | ack -xl 'pattern2' | ack -x 'pattern3'
```

This is an **AND** operator and not the OR operator given in the other solutions.

Comment: JEEZ! how often was I screwing around with `find` and `xargs` and what not when `ack` alone just does the trick, too! :+1:

Answer (score 1):

For `ag`, as of verion 0.19.2 the default is to search in directories and files recursively.

To search for multiple patterns, you can use similiar syntax as `ack`

```
ag 'pattern1|pattern2'
```

will search for both `pattern1` and `pattern2`.

In case you don't want to search recursively, you can set the search depth to 1 by the switch `--depth NUM`

Therefore,

```
ag 'pattern1|pattern2' --depth 1
```

will only search in the current directory for both patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but for my use case, the pipe solution didn't work.

I simply used the output of `ack -l` as the input to grep. For example, to quickly find all Javascript files containing `string 1` and `string 2`:

```
grep "string 2" `ack -l --js "string 1"`
```