# How can I use ack to find files that contain two patterns?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, ack

I'm trying to search for files that contain 2 patterns. I'm guessing piping is the way to go but I'm doing something wrong, because the following doesn't work:

```
ack -l "pattern1" | ack -l "pattern2"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does it have to be `ack`? `awk`, `grep` or `sed` can offer the same. Also, related: [Searching multiple patterns (words) with ack?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26275582/1983854)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take it from your question that you want files that contains pattern1 and also contain pattern2, even if they are on different lines.

Here's one way to do it:

```
ack -l pattern2 $(ack -l pattern1)
```

Here's another:

```
ack -l pattern1 | ack -l -x pattern2
```

The `-x` says "Get the list of files to search from standard input, as if I were the `xargs` program."  (This is assuming you're using ack 2.x or higher)

Comment: We added `-x` because the `xargs` way of thinking is so ubiquitous, and this pattern of `ack -l that $(ack -l this)` is so common, and the `-x` makes it a more straightforward pipeline.

Comment: Perhaps add `-s` to the 1st snippet to silence the potentially confusing error message that would result from the 1st `ack` invocation not returning anything (in case of not matching).

Comment: Great! Thanks Andy! That 2nd way did it for me (with the first snippet I got a bunch of errors: "Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at /usr/local/bin/ack line XXX"

Comment: I removed the quotes from the first example that someone else had added earlier.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: If the intent is to find **both patterns *anywhere* in the file (not necessarily on the same line)**, **[Andy Lester's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8454/andy-lester) offers simple solutions**.

---

`-l` outputs the *filename* rather than the matching *line(s)*, so do not use `-l` in your *first* `ack` invocation (or else the second one will only receive the filename as its input).

However, as @Mr. Llama correctly points out, even that wouldn't work, because the 2nd `ack` would print `-` (stdin) in the event of a match, given that its input comes from a *pipe* rather than a *file*.

```
ack "pattern1" | ack -l "pattern2" # !! prints '-' in case of match
```

Generally, `-l` only makes sense with *filenames* as operands.

Aside from that, however, **your command would only match if (at least one) *single* line contained *both* search terms**.

**If that is truly the intent**, you could get away with a ***single* invocation of `ack`**, using regex alternation (the parentheses are used for visual clarity and aren't strictly necessary):

```
ack -l "(pattern1).*(pattern2)|(pattern2).*(pattern1)" file
```

Comment: Wouldn't the second `ack` simply print `stdin`, or is that something that grep does?  Example: `echo Hello | grep -l "e"`

Comment: @Mr.Llama: Excellent point, thanks. It prints `-`, which represents `stdin`.

Comment: Thanks mklement0, once for your answer and another time for pointing me to Andy's answer!